# RDP Server giving C0000006 for Application Programs

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, memory-error

Recently, our RDP Server is having some trouble.

Remote users will use the **RDP Server** to connect to the **Application Server**, while users that are in-building, will connect directly to the Application Server.

The issue recently is that remote users, using the **RDP Server** to connect to the **Application Server**, will get the C0000006 External Exception Error. When the first user gets this error, the error will spread out to users slowly until everyone using **Program#1** and **Program#2** get the C0000006 error. Rebooting the **RDP Server** fixes the issue the majority of the time.

I am not sure of what the issue would be that would be causing the C0000006 error for these two Programs (they speak with one another), but usually the first precursor to this creeping up on users are **Program#1** and **Program#2** showing up blank in Task Manager like so:

[image: RDP Server C0000006 precursor.png]

I know this is a long shot, but any idea what may be causing this? It seems like the communication between the **RDP Server** and the **Application Server**. IT would love to fix this issue on our end, but if it is in fact a programming error, it is the 3rd party consultant's programming fix, and must be dealt with by them.

Answer (score 1):

0xC0000006 errors arise when your program goes to page more data for the EXE into memory, but couldn't.  Usually this is caused by an I/O issue when attempting to read the data.

So ensure that the connectivity between the application server and the RDP server is stable, and that the storage in the application server is responding and sending data quickly.  Basically you want no unexpected drops, or long delays in data coming into the RDP server.

Another option (or additional action), since judging by the icon shown in your screenshot, is that since the application is written in Delphi, it can be recompiled to include a header that will tell Windows to load the whole program into memory at once, avoiding the need to page in data later, thus avoiding the error...

```
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

And ensure that the `Winapi.Windows` is included in the `Uses` section.

The first flag tells it to load entirely into memory if the program is located on a removable drive (i.e.: a flash drive) and the second tells it to do it if the program is located on a network share (as yours probably is).

More info is available on StakcOverflow:

- [External exception C0000006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317886/external-exception-c0000006)
- [Recommended PE header settings for Delphi 7 application running on terminal server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378674/recommended-pe-header-settings-for-delphi-7-application-running-on-terminal-serv)